# How can my ItemsControl get the width property (from Items)

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, controls, itemscontrol

I have a small problem how to set the `ItemsControl` Property `Width`. I use `Datatemplates` to fill my `ItemControl`. Every Item is a small `Grid` (Text and Rectangle) in a `Canvas`.

When I use the `ItemsControl` in a `Window` the `ActualWidth` (and `DesiredWidth`) is always `0.0`.

Only when i hardcode the `Width` Property of the `Canvas` the ItemsControl has a size. But that is far from perfect. I would rather like when the `Control` gets the `width` (or `DesiredWidth`) from the biggest Item.

Here is a short code sample:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding mySource}"
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource myTemplate}">

<ItemsControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type type:myType}"  x:Key="myTemplate">
        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Height="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Fill="Blue"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Margin="3"
                       Text="{Binding Text}"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       TextAlignment="Left"/>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <v:PositionMultiConverter x:Key="PositionMultiConverter"/>
</ItemsControl.Resources>

<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PositionMultiConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Position"/>
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="canvas"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" IsItemsHost="True" Width="20"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: A `Canvas` does not stretch it's size according to the Size of it's children. Can you use a single-celled `Grid` instead and just set the `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Bottom` in your `ItemContainerStyle`?

Comment: That's worth thinking about. In my solution you see that i bind each item with the height (position) of the items. how to do that in a grid.

Comment: I believe `Canvas.Bottom` will work providing you set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Bottom` in your `ItemContainerStyle`, although if `Canvas.Bottom` doesn't work then you can just set the Bottom margin instead

Comment: `HorizontalAlignment` can't be set to `Bottom`. And I don't know what exactly you mean when you say set the Bottom margin. And to be clear: The height of each individual Item should be different (calculated by the PositionMulticonverter).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `VerticalAlignment`. It will make each item be placed at the bottom of the `Grid` instead of stretching to fill the entire height. I think `Canvas.Bottom` works in a Grid if the `VerticalAlignment` is something other than `Stretch`, however if that's not the case then you can change your converter to set the `Margin` property instead of `Canvas.Bottom`, and have it return a `Thickness` object with the Bottom value set to whatever your `Canvas.Bottom` would have been, such as `0,0,0,5`

Comment: I have some problems with that. First of all (as far as i know) Thickness is not in Pixel (like height) but in device independent unit (1/96 inch). And even then, I did run it. And from the 2 elements (`rectangle` and `textbox`) only the `rectangle` was "shifted".